# Swift, How to get information from a custom annotation on clicked

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I've got the following custom annotation class:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class LocationMapAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    var title: String?
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var location: Location

    init(title: String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, location: Location) {
        self.title = title
        self.coordinate = coordinate
        self.location = location
    }
}
```

I am loading the annotations into a map view like this:

```
for i in 0..<allLocations.count{
            //Add an annotation
            let l: Location = self.allLocations[i] as! Location
            let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(l.latitude as Double, l.longitude as Double)
            let annotation = LocationAnnotation(title: l.name, coordinate: coordinates, location: l)
            mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        }
```

And I am wanting to get the `Location` object from the selected annotation. Currently I have this method which is called when ever I tap an annotation, but I am unsure how to retrieve the specific object from the annotation.

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView) {
    print("Annotation selected")

    //performSegueWithIdentifier("locationInfoSegue", sender: self)
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get your Annotation within didSelectAnnotationView, which will then give you MKAnnotationView. This MKAnnotationView has MKAnnotation as an object.

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView) {
    println("Annotation selected")

    if let annotation = view.annotation as? LocationMapAnnotation {
        println("Your annotation title: \(annotation.title)");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks so much it just fixed it!

Comment: if let annotation = view.annotation as?  LocationMapAnnotation
is this a valid comparison?
between an annotation(MKAnnotation) and “LocationMapAnnotation”(a model class - Mappable)

Comment: @SyedUzairAhmed It is not comparison but a standard way to type cast in swift. https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TypeCasting.html