# How to get all information from annotation pin in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, mapkit

I was wondering how to get all the information from a annotation in swift when tapped on.
There is this article:
[Swift, How to get information from a custom annotation on clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37320485/swift-how-to-get-information-from-a-custom-annotation-on-clicked)

But that doesn't answer my question. I made some modifications to the code.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    if let annotationTitle = view.annotation?.title {
        if let annotationPhone = view.annotation?.phoneNumber as? MKAnnotationView {
            print("User tapped on annotation with title: \(annotationPhone!)")
        }
        print("User tapped on annotation with title: \(annotationTitle!)")
    }
}
```

Creating the pin if this helps at all:

```
let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
annotation.coordinate = item.placemark.coordinate
annotation.title = item.name
annotation.subtitle = "Coffee Shop"
self.map.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

But I get the error:

```
Value of type 'MKAnnotation' has no member 'phoneNumber'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `as? MKAnnotationView`. Did you used a custom `MKAnnotationView` or custom `MKAnnotation` with a property `phoneNumber`? if yes, use this one: `if let annotationView as ? MyCustomAnnotationView, let annotationPhone = view.annotation.phoneNumber {`, or whatever is the path you used (for the example, I assumed it was `MKAnnotationView`).

Comment: I am using MKPointAnnotation

Answer (score 0):

Just subclass `MKPointAnnotation` with property called `phoneNumber` :

```
class PhoneAnnotation : MKPointAnnotation {
    var phoneNumber: String?
}
```

After this you can get the `phoneNumber` value (and other custom values) from annotation like this:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    if let phoneNumber = (view.annotation as? PhoneAnnotation)?.phoneNumber {

    }
}
```

Comment: Cool, I got no errors but now I have a bug. The if statement isn't running! Why might this be?

Comment: @Albert maybe phoneNumber is nil or annotation is not instance of your custom class

Comment: Mabye.. What should I do then? And thanks for the help.